# I want to record video through camera Android

Tags: android

i want to record video through camera and before we start recording camera preview should be there and after we stop the recording camera preview should be there

i wrote this code it only preview camera before we start recording.when i stop recording camera is not preview. help me

```
MainActivity  


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    Button st;
    TextView live, stopWatch;
    boolean recording = false;
    boolean loop = false;
    EditText barcode;
    TextView head;
    ArrayList<Subtitle> Sub;
    long MillisecondTime, StartTime, TimeBuff, UpdateTime = 0L;
    int Seconds, Minutes, MilliSeconds;
    Handler handler;
    AVLoadingIndicatorView loading;
    LinearLayout videoSurface;
    LinearLayout cameraSurface;

    Timer t;
    SimpleDateFormat d2;
    SimpleDateFormat d1;

    boolean duration = true;
    boolean durationVal = false;
    int p = 0;


    private CameraPreview mCameraView = null;
    FrameLayout camera_view;
    SurfaceView cameraView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "C3dssImageProcessing");

        if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
            myDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(CameraView);





        st = (Button) findViewById(R.id.actionbtn);
        live = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.liveStatus);
        barcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.barcode);
        stopWatch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stopwatch);

        loading = (AVLoadingIndicatorView) findViewById(R.id.load);
        head = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header1);



        initiateCamera(); 


        barcode.setEnabled(false);


        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
        );
        live.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        holder = cameraView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        st.setClickable(true);
        st.setOnClickListener(this);



        barcode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "beforeTextChanged");

                if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
                    myDirectory.mkdirs();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence ss, int start, int before, int count) {
                File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "onTextChanged");

                if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
                    myDirectory.mkdirs();
                }

                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on text changed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Subtitle subtitle = new Subtitle();
                subtitle.setBarcode(barcode.getText().toString());

                if (barcode.getText().length() > 12 && !(Sub == null)) {
                    barcode.setEnabled(false);

                    //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "barcode fired ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (stopWatch.getText().length() <= 5) {
                        subtitle.setStartTime("00:"+stopWatch.getText().toString());
                        String str = stopWatch.getText().toString();
                        String substring = str.length() > 2 ? str.substring(str.length() - 2) : str;
                        int second = Integer.parseInt(substring);
                        second += 5;
                        if (second == 60) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 00;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("01:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 00;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("00:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }

                        if (second == 61) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 02;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("01:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 02;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("00:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }
                        if (second == 62) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 03;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("01:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 03;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("00:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }

                        if (second == 62) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 04;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("01:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 04;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("00:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }
                        if (second == 63) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 05;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("01:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 05;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("00:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }
                        if (second == 64) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 06;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("01:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 06;
                                subtitle.setEndTime("00:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }
                        if (second < 60) {
                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            subtitle.setEndTime("00:" + minitute + ":" + second);
                        }
                    } else {
                        subtitle.setStartTime(stopWatch.getText().toString());
                        String str = stopWatch.getText().toString();
                        String substring = str.length() > 2 ? str.substring(str.length() - 2) : str;
                        int second = Integer.parseInt(substring);
                        second += 5;

                        if (second == 60) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            String s1 = str.substring(4, 5);
                            int hour = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s1);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 00;
                                hour += 1;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 00;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }

                        if (second == 61) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            String s1 = str.substring(4, 5);
                            int hour = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 02;
                                hour += 1;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 02;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }
                        if (second == 62) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            String s1 = str.substring(4, 5);
                            int hour = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 03;
                                hour += 1;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 03;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }

                        if (second == 62) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            String s1 = str.substring(4, 5);
                            int hour = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 04;
                                hour += 1;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 04;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }
                        if (second == 63) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            String s1 = str.substring(4, 5);
                            int hour = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 05;
                                hour += 1;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 05;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }
                        if (second == 64) {

                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            String s1 = str.substring(4, 5);
                            int hour = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            if (minitute == 59) {
                                minitute = 00;
                                second = 06;
                                hour += 1;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            } else {
                                minitute += 1;
                                second = 06;
                                subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                            }
                        }
                        if (second > 60) {
                            String s = str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
                            String s1 = str.substring(4, 5);
                            int hour = Integer.parseInt(s);
                            int minitute = Integer.parseInt(s1);
                            second = 00;
                            subtitle.setEndTime(hour + minitute + ":" + second);
                        }

                    }
                    Sub.add(subtitle);

                    ValueHolder.Sub = Sub;

                    Timer t = new Timer(true);
                    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    barcode.setText("");
                                    barcode.setEnabled(true);
                                }


                            });
                        }
                    }, 5000);
                    File myDirectorytest = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "onTextChangedValueHolder");

                    if (!myDirectorytest.exists()) {
                        myDirectorytest.mkdirs();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }


        });
    }

    private void initRecorder() {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);

        recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
        setDayTimestamp();
        setvideoNamestamp();
        recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/C3dssImageProcessing/" + ValueHolder.dayFile + "/" + ValueHolder.videoName + "/" + ValueHolder.videoName + ".mp4");
        recorder.setMaxDuration(86400000); // 50 seconds
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(1000000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
    }

    private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("illegal :",e.toString());
           // finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("IOEXCEPTION :",e.toString());
            //finish();
        }
    }

    public void onClick(final View v) {


        final Thread stopWh = new Thread() {
            final int[] hour = new int[1];
            final int[] minute = new int[1];
            final int[] second = new int[1];


            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    if (!durationVal) {
                        second[0] = 00;
                        minute[0] = 00;
                        hour[0] = 00;

                    }
                    if (duration) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                durationVal = true;
                                second[0] += 1;
                                if (second[0] == 59) {

                                    minute[0] += 1;
                                    second[0] = 0;
                                }
                                if (minute[0] == 60) {

                                    hour[0] = 1;
                                    minute[0] = 0;
                                }
                                if (hour[0] > 0) {
                                    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");

                                    stopWatch.setText(formatter.format(hour[0]) + ":" + formatter.format(minute[0]) + "" + formatter.format(second[0]));
                                } else {
                                    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");
                                    stopWatch.setText(formatter.format(minute[0]) + ":" + formatter.format(second[0]));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }


        };


        if (recording) {

            barcode.setEnabled(false);
            barcode.setFocusable(false);


            cameraView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


             initiateCamera();





            loading.hide();

         camera_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            duration = false;
            durationVal = false;
            recording = false;

            createSRTfile(ValueHolder.Sub);
            stopWatch.setText("00:00");
            p = 1;
            live.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            live.setSelected(false);
            st.setText("START");

            barcode.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            barcode.setFocusable(true);
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
            );

            loop = true;


        } else {


            recording = true;



            barcode.setEnabled(true);
            barcode.setFocusable(true);

            if (p == 0) {


             camera_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

              stopCamera();



                initRecorder();
                stopWh.start();
                cameraView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {

            camera_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                stopCamera();

                initRecorder();
                duration = true;
                cameraView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }


            recorder.start();
            loading.show();
            barcode.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            barcode.setFocusable(true);
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
            );
            Sub = new ArrayList<>();


            live.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            st.setText("STOP");

            live.setText("Live Recording...");
            live.setSelected(true);


            File myDirectoryDay1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "C3dssImageProcessing/" + ValueHolder.dayFile);

            if (!myDirectoryDay1.exists()) {
                myDirectoryDay1.mkdirs();
            }


            File myDirectoryDay = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "C3dssImageProcessing/" + ValueHolder.dayFile + "/" + ValueHolder.videoName);

            if (!myDirectoryDay.exists()) {
                myDirectoryDay.mkdirs();
            }


        }


    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {



        prepareRecorder();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {


    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "surface destroyed on main Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




        if (recording) {
            recorder.stop();

            recording = false;
        }
        recorder.reset();



    }

    private void setDayTimestamp() {

        ValueHolder.dayFile = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new java.util.Date());
        File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "C3dssImageProcessing/" + ValueHolder.dayFile);

        if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
            myDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

    }

    private void setvideoNamestamp() {

        ValueHolder.videoName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss").format(new java.util.Date());

        File myDirectoryDay = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "C3dssImageProcessing/" + ValueHolder.dayFile + "/" + ValueHolder.videoName);

        if (!myDirectoryDay.exists()) {
          //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "v name : "+ValueHolder.videoName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            myDirectoryDay.mkdirs();
        }
    }




    private void createSRTfile(ArrayList<Subtitle> sub) {

        if (!(sub == null)) {

            if (sub.size() > 0) {
                try {

                    BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/C3dssImageProcessing/" + ValueHolder.dayFile + "/" + ValueHolder.videoName + "/" + ValueHolder.videoName + ".srt"));

                    // PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/sdcard/C3dssImageProcessing/" + ValueHolder.dayFile + "/" + ValueHolder.videoName + ".srt", "UTF-8");
                    for (int i = 0; i < sub.size(); i++) {

                        if (i == 0) {
                            writer1.write("1");

                            //writer.println("1");
                            writer1.newLine();
                        } else {
                            int p = i+1;
                            writer1.write(p);
                           writer1.newLine();
                        }

                        writer1.write(sub.get(i).getStartTime() + ",560 --> " + sub.get(i).getEndTime() + ",580 ");
                        //  writer1.write(newline);
                        writer1.newLine();
                        writer1.write(sub.get(i).getBarcode()+"\n");
                        writer1.newLine();
                        writer1.newLine();


                    }
                    writer1.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        super.onBackPressed();
    }




    private void initiateCamera(){

        camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camerPreview);
        Camera mCamera = null;
        try{
            mCamera = Camera.open();//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if(mCamera != null) {
            mCameraView = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
            ValueHolder.cam = mCamera;

            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
        }


    }

    private void stopCamera(){


       ValueHolder.cam.stopPreview();

        ValueHolder.cam.release();



    }

}
```

Comment: too much code. Nobody wants to read it all. Please put some effort and localize the problem.

Comment: Use this.. Might be helpful for you..
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Recording_and_Image_Capture_on_Android_using_Camera_Intents

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html

Comment: Please paste that section of code where you have problem. no one read your entire code..

Comment: i failed with this method . i am asking from you guys is there any possible way to do that

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You could use this library to achieve the results.
[Material Camera](https://github.com/afollestad/material-camera?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2827)

Sample Code for using this lib after integrating the lib,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static int CAMERA_RQ = 6969;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new MaterialCamera(this)
            .start(CAMERA_RQ);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Received recording or error from MaterialCamera
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_RQ) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to: " + data.getDataString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if(data != null) {
                Exception e = (Exception) data.getSerializableExtra(MaterialCamera.ERROR_EXTRA);
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a link can't be treated as an answer

Comment: @RukshanWithanage, looks like you want to get banned much more than to get an answer. I'll explain, what is a problem. StackOverflow is designed **not to solve your problem**, but to **collect a database of solutions**. Answering with a link only is clearly stated as a **vary bad answer**. If you didn't read the rules, then you have neither permission to use SO nor to tell who should shut up.

Comment: @RukshanWithanage sorry for the bad answer. i have updated the answer with some tips.